# Failed Deploying MVC 5 to dedicated server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, iis, full-trust

After discovering that medium trust is no longer supported in MVC 5, I have published my application to a dedicated server - adjusted the .NET Trust Levels to Full Trust and I still get the following error:

> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

Anyone got any ideas?

I have included...In the web config.

```
  <system.web>
         <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
       </system.web>
```

Comment: Are you have full access control on dedicated server with current machine account? If it's true, try read this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555466. Your changes in web.config should be enough as full trust level, but it depends on current account privilege level.

Comment: Managed to get it to work. There was an underlying issue with WebGreaser. Thanks for the help @TetsuyaYamamoto